# XML comments in Resources.Designer.cs?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, resources, xml-comments

In my Visual Studio 2008 project, I have this project with Resources.resx which contains images and strings. In order to force myself and everyone else to write *at least* the XML comments, I enabled the generation of XML comments in the build tab of the project's property. Now Visual Studio gives me some warnings if there are undocumented classes, methods, … which is great!

However, all of the images in the automatically generated Resources.Designer.cs do not have any XML comments (while the strings do), so I get several compiler warnings of missing XML comments which I actually cannot do anything about, because changes to that file would probably overwritten anyways.

Is there any chance to either

- tell the compiler to ignore XML comments in designer generated code, or
- force Visual Studio 2008 to write the resource comment into the generated code?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio *should* be doing this, but it's not, so make your file like this:

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
<contents go here ...>
#pragma warning enable 1591
```

Comment: This really doesn't help...  Where are we supposed to stick the pragmas?  The problem file, resources.designer.cs, is generated automatically.  Any changes there will get overwritten the next time someone updates the resources.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [custom](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/customtoolsexp.aspx) [tool](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/e72dc18d-50dc-4fe4-9a54-24f1d3e830fd) to generate the designer.cs file for the .resx file. The custom tool would call **[resgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1%28VS.80%29.aspx)** to generate the .cs file and then surround the content with **#pragma** statements to ignore the warnings for missing xml comment:

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
...
#pragma warning enable 1591
```